# calcific tendonitis in the shoulder - lavage treatment effectiveness

Tags: injections, shoulder

I have heard of the needle lavage treatment for calcific tendonitis, where they inject water solution near the calcification area in the shoulder and drawing it out several times to dissolve the calcification.

http://www.ajronline.org/doi/full/10.2214/AJR.07.2254

Today, is it effective ? Are there good results in the area ?